# Centos 7: Whois And Repositories

Tags: yum, repository, whois

Everytime I try to install whois with:

```
yum install whois -y
```

I get an error that says:

```
No package whois available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Looks to me that repositories are messed up. Can I get some detailed help?

Comment: Are you sure there actually exists such a yum package?

Comment: of course!!! i use it everyday on my servers

Comment: On your servers, what is the output of `rpm -q -f $(which whois)`

Comment: this is the output : # jwhois-4.0-19.el6.x86_64 , but this is only because i installed jwhois

Comment: Same problem on CentOS 8

Answer (score 1):

The package name is jwhois, you may install it with:

```
# yum -y install jwhois
```

Answer (score 0):

In Cent OS & you have to go an extra mile in case you are getting the error:  No package jwhois available

**Type the following command:**

`yum whatprovides *bin/whois*`

The response will be:
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Bla bla bla

**Then type**

`yum install whois`

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

Bla bla bla

**Press yes at any Y/n area.**

That's it, whois installed.